# Android - LocationManager requestLocationUpdates - location updates not consistent

Tags: android, geolocation, location

I am trying to get location updates every 10 minutes, but the location update time is inconsistent. Sometime I get location update after 10 minutes and sometime I get location update after 2 hours. The app gets location updates on a background thread.

Here is the code:

```
_locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                10 *  60 * 1000,
                0, 
                _locationListener,
                _gpsHandlerThread.getLooper());
```

I also tried setting both values, minTime(10) and minDistance(10 meters), but then I get updates even after 1-2 minutes. I am not sure if minTime and minDistance has OR logic, meaning if time interval is 10 minutes or user has moved 10 meters or it has and logic.

My requirement is - Get user location every 10 minutes, if user has moved 10 meters away from last location.

How can I achieve this?I ask for help with little explanation how it works.

Comment: If you are using `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` it can take up to twenty minutes to get the first fix from the satellite - not to mention you need clear view of the sky i.e. doesn't work if you're indoor. `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`, on the other hand, can give you location update as soon as your device connected to a wireless network - downside is that this method is less accurate than the GPS method you've used.

Answer (score 1):

user this Handler to get Location

```
private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run()
    {
        try
            {

                Location myLocation = mGoogleMap.getMyLocation();
                secndLocationListener.onLocationChanged(myLocation);
            }
        catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.getStackTraceString(e);
            }

    }
    };
```

call this

```
   customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread , 10 *  60 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is not through requestLocationUpdates, but rather through using a timer to start updates periodically. That should spare you from wearing out your battery needlessly. So I end up doing something like this:

1. I have some checks to see if I like the GPS value.
2. If I'm satisfied with the GPS, then I remove updates, and start a timer to start getting updates again.
3. I always get updates upon resuming the application.

Code to restart the GPS updates might look like this:

```
Timer mTimer;
private void sendFinalGps() {
    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    mTimer = new Timer();
    mTimer.schedule(new findGpsTime(), getTimeBetweenUpdates());
}
```